# Unity Coroutines and objects not being removed with Destroy()

Tags: unity-game-engine, coroutine

Currently working on a Unity project and I'm having this issue where an object is not being destroyed.  the child objects are just 2 images and a text object with no other scripts.  Sometimes the object is removed correctly, but other times it is not.  Can anyone see why this is?   MEC is a replacement for unity coroutines but the issue happens with Unity Coroutines also and it was my first attempt to fix it.

The issue seems to happen more under load.

```
using MEC;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(typeof(CanvasGroup))]
public class UINotificationEffect : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Private
    private CanvasGroup canvas_group;
    private float time_passed;
    private bool fading_out;

    // Public
    public float alive_time = 3.0f;
    public float fade_time = 0.5f;
    public string message = "Notification message";

    private void Awake()
    {
        canvas_group = GetComponent<CanvasGroup>();
        canvas_group.alpha = 0;
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        gameObject.GetComponentInChildren<TextMeshProUGUI>().text = message;     
        Timing.RunCoroutine(FadeTo(1.0f, fade_time), gameObject);
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        // At alive time end, fade out and get rid of this gameobject
        time_passed += Time.deltaTime;
        if (time_passed >= alive_time && !fading_out)
        {
            Timing.RunCoroutine(FadeTo(0.0f, fade_time), gameObject);
            fading_out = true;
        }

        // Destroy gameobject after alive time + fade time is over.
        if (fading_out && canvas_group.alpha <= 0.02f)
        {
            Timing.KillCoroutines(gameObject);
            Destroy(gameObject, 1f);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Fade alpha of the canvas group in a certain direction (controlled by alpha_value).
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="alpha_value">Fade to full (1.0) or fade to nothing (0.0)?</param>
    /// <param name="transition_time">The fading time of the alpha.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    IEnumerator<float> FadeTo(float alpha_value, float transition_time)
    {
        if (gameObject != null && gameObject.activeInHierarchy)
        {
            float alpha = canvas_group.alpha;
            for (float t = 0.0f; t <= 1.0f; t += Time.deltaTime / transition_time)
            {
                canvas_group.alpha = Mathf.Lerp(alpha, alpha_value, t);
                yield return Timing.WaitForOneFrame;
            }
        }
        yield break;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Update the text that should be displayed.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="text">The new message.</param>
    public void UpdateText(string text)
    {
        message = text;
        gameObject.GetComponentInChildren<TextMeshProUGUI>().text = message;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Stop all coroutines when the gameobject is destroyed.
    /// </summary>
    private void OnDestroy()
    {
        //StopAllCoroutines();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have a guarantee that the loop in `FadeTo` ever runs with `t` approximately equal to `1f` (really, you only know that it will be run at least once for `t = 0f`). Therefore, your alpha may never go below `0.2f`, in which case, `Destroy` is never called.

Add a line at the end of your fade loop to set the `canvas_group.alpha` exactly to `alpha_value`:

```
IEnumerator<float> FadeTo(float alpha_value, float transition_time)
{
    if (gameObject != null && gameObject.activeInHierarchy)
    {
        float alpha = canvas_group.alpha;
        for (float t = 0.0f; t <= 1.0f; t += Time.deltaTime / transition_time)
        {
            canvas_group.alpha = Mathf.Lerp(alpha, alpha_value, t);
            yield return Timing.WaitForOneFrame;
        }

        canvas_group.alpha = alpha_value;
    }
    yield break;
}
```